# Powershell Enter-PSSession use current credential

Tags: powershell, remote, credentials, powershell-2.0

I want to use Windows Powershell to start up a VirtualBox VM and then Enter-PSSession to manage the machine on an automated nightly system, which means I will be asleep when this is happening and not able to enter in a password.

I have two choices as far as I know:
1. Use the current credentials, as these are on a domain that the VM accepts credentials from.
2. Hardcode in my credentials (probably the same as the current credentials)

I do not like option 2 as I have been tasked with the avoidance of hardcoded credentials where possible, but I do not know whether option 1 is possible. How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Enter-PSSession cmdlet "-Credential" is not a mandatory parameter. So if you don't specify credential, your current credential will be used.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before and it didn't work, but that's because I was logged on as a different user than I intended to be. Managing a desktop is hard enough without a remote desktop inside that and a virtual machine inside the remote desktop... Ok, thanks for prompting me to try this again.

Comment: Also you have to use New-PSSession in a script, Enter-PSSession is for interactive remote session.